# "Sound" Recognition in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sound-recognition

I'm working on an applicaion in Swift and I was thinking about a way to get **Non-Speech** sound recognition in my project.

I mean is there a way in which I can take in sound inputs and match them against some predefined sounds already incorporated in the project and if a match occurs, it should do some particular action?

Is there any way to do the above? I'm thinking breaking up the sounds and doing the checks, but can't seem to get any further than that.

Comment: Requires serious technical knowledge. For someone lacking a detailed scientific plan for how to do this, maybe it would be a good idea to write some other kind of app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal experience follows matt's comment above: requires serious technical knowledge.

There are several ways to do this, and one is typically as follows: extract some properties from the sound segment of interest (audio feature extraction), and classify this audio feature vector with some kind of machine learning technique. This typically requires some training phase where the machine learning technique was given some examples to learn what sounds you want to recognize (your predefined sounds) so that it can build a model from that data.

Without knowing what types of sounds you're aiming for to be recognized, maybe our C/C++ SDK available here might do the trick for you: http://www.samplesumo.com/percussive-sound-recognition
There's a technical demo on that page that you can download and try with your sounds. It's a C/C++ library, and there is a Mac, Windows and iOS version, so you should be able to integrate it with a Swift app on iOS. Maybe this will allow you to do what you need?

If you want to develop your own technology, you may want to start by finding and reading some scientific papers using the keywords "sound classification", "audio recognition", "machine listening", "audio feature classification", ...

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

We've been developing a bunch of cool tools to speed up iOS development, specially in Swift. One of these tools is what we called [TLSphinx](http://blog.tryolabs.com/2015/06/15/tlsphinx-automatic-speech-recognition-asr-in-swift/): a Swift wrapper around Pocketsphinx which **can perform speech recognition without the audio leaving the device**.

I assume TLSphinx can help you solve your problem since it is a totally open source library. Search for it on Github ('TLSphinx') and you can also download our iOS app ('Tryolabs Mobile Showcase') and try the module live to see how it works.
Hope it is useful!

Best!